# run timr telebot error async_telebot.py:551 MainThread

Tags: python-3.x

i got the flowing error when i try to run telebot async

```
(async_telebot.py:551 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "object bool can't be used in 'await' expression"
```

version of telebot are i using:

last version

What OS are you using?

mint Linux
What version of python are you using?

python 3.10

Comment: also report in the github repo
https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/2081